# Shift selected elements by one and return their updated indices

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

**Background:**

I have recently decompiled an old project of mine, whose source code I lost, and am refactoring all this terrible code I wrote years ago.

I have a list with items displayed by the UI, the items can be moved up and down and multi-selection is allowed. I have a method `int[] moveUp(int[] selectedIndices)` which updates the model and returns the new indices of the shifted elements in the list (so that I can update UI after model change).

`selectedIndices` comes from `JList#getSelectedIndices` which guarantees a sorted order with no repetitions.

**Old solution:**

```
public int[] moveUp(int[] selectedIndices) {
    Action[] array = concatenate(new Action[]{null}, actions.toArray(new Action[0]));
    for (int i = 0; i < selectedIndices.length; i++) {
        swap(array, selectedIndices[i] + 1, selectedIndices[i]);
        selectedIndices[i] -= 1;
    }
    actions = new ArrayList<>(this.actions.size());
    for (Action action : array) {
        if (action != null) {
            actions.add(action);
        }
    }
    return selectedIndices;
}
```

**Problem:**

If I have actions `[a, b, c, d]` and `selectedIndices` are `[0, 1, 3]`, although the result will be correct (`[a, b, d, c]`), the returned new indices are `[-1, 0, 2]`, while they should be `[0, 1, 2]`.

**New solution:**

```
public int[] moveUp(int[] selectedIndices) {
    List<Action> selectedActions = stream(selectedIndices).mapToObj(actions::get).collect(toList());

    actions.add(0, null);
    for (int selectedIndex : selectedIndices) {
        swap(actions, selectedIndex + 1, selectedIndex);
    }
    actions.remove(null);

    return selectedActions.stream().mapToInt(actions::indexOf).toArray();
}
```

**Problem:**

It is neither clean, nor efficient.

**Question:**

How to implement it in a clean and efficient way?

**MCVE and tests:**

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.shazam</groupId>
        <artifactId>shazamcrest</artifactId>
        <version>0.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

public interface Action {

}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static java.util.Arrays.stream;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;

public class Actions {

    private List<Action> actions = new ArrayList<>();

    public void add(Action action) {
        this.actions.add(action);
    }

    public int[] moveUp(int[] selectedIndices) {
        List<Action> selectedActions = stream(selectedIndices).mapToObj(actions::get).collect(toList());

        actions.add(0, null);
        for (int selectedIndex : selectedIndices) {
            swap(actions, selectedIndex + 1, selectedIndex);
        }
        actions.remove(null);

        return selectedActions.stream().mapToInt(actions::indexOf).toArray();
    }

    private static <T> void swap(List<T> list, int index, int index2) {
        T t = list.get(index);
        list.set(index, list.get(index2));
        list.set(index2, t);
    }

}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

public class FakeAction implements Action {

    @SuppressWarnings("FieldCanBeLocal") // used by shazamcrest
    private final String name;

    private FakeAction(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    static Actions actionsWithElements(int... elementsNames) {
        Actions actions = new Actions();
        for (int elementName : elementsNames) {
            actions.add(new FakeAction(String.valueOf(elementName)));
        }
        return actions;
    }

    static int[] indices(int... indices) {
        return indices;
    }

}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

import org.junit.Test;

import static com.shazam.shazamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
import static com.shazam.shazamcrest.matcher.Matchers.sameBeanAs;
import static FakeAction.actionsWithElements;
import static FakeAction.indices;

public class ActionsMoveUpTest {

    @Test
    public void movesUpSingleAction() {
        Actions actions = actionsWithElements(0, 1, 2, 3);

        actions.moveUp(indices(2));

        assertThat(actions, sameBeanAs(actionsWithElements(0, 2, 1, 3)));
    }

    @Test
    public void movesUpMultipleActions() {
        Actions actions = actionsWithElements(0, 1, 2, 3);

        actions.moveUp(indices(1, 3));

        assertThat(actions, sameBeanAs(actionsWithElements(1, 0, 3, 2)));
    }

    @Test
    public void doesNothingWhenArrayOfIndicesToMoveUpIsEmpty() {
        Actions actions = actionsWithElements(0, 1, 2, 3);

        actions.moveUp(indices());

        assertThat(actions, sameBeanAs(actionsWithElements(0, 1, 2, 3)));
    }

    @Test
    public void doesNotLoseSelectionWhenMovingUpTheTopAction() {
        Actions actions = actionsWithElements(0, 1, 2, 3);

        int[] newIndices = actions.moveUp(indices(0));

        assertThat(newIndices, sameBeanAs(indices(0)));
    }

    @Test
    public void movesUpOnlyThoseActionsWhichAreNotOnTheTopAlready() {
        Actions actions = actionsWithElements(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);

        actions.moveUp(indices(0, 1, 4, 6));

        assertThat(actions, sameBeanAs(actionsWithElements(0, 1, 2, 4, 3, 6, 5)));
    }

    @Test
    public void doesNotLoseSelectionOfTheTopActionsWhenMovingMultipleActions() {
        Actions actions = actionsWithElements(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);

        int[] newIndices = actions.moveUp(indices(0, 1, 4, 6));

        assertThat(newIndices, sameBeanAs(indices(0, 1, 3, 5)));
    }

}
```

Comment: I guess this kind of question belongs to https://codereview.stackexchange.com, because "clean and efficient" is very opinionated.

Comment: @SzymonStepniak clean - I agree, efficient - not sure. The last stream has `O(n*m)` complexity. I see it more as a question "how to solve problem X", not "what do you think about my solution to problem X".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Misha's observation, I came with something even simpler.

The key is that if `selectedIndices[i] == i`, the element doesn't move:

```
actions:               [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i]
index:                  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8
selectedIndices:       [0, 1, 2,       5, 6,    8]
elements to move left:                 f  g     i
output:                [a, b, c, d, f, g, e, i, h]
```

From here, it can be easily implemented with `O(m)` time complexity (where `m = selectedIndices.length`) as:

```
public int[] moveUp(int[] selectedIndices) {
    int[] newIndices = Arrays.copyOf(selectedIndices, selectedIndices.length);

    for (int i = 0; i < selectedIndices.length; i++) {
        if (selectedIndices[i] != i) {
            swap(actions, selectedIndices[i], selectedIndices[i] - 1);
            newIndices[i]--;
        }
    }

    return newIndices;
}
```

Or with some Java streams:

```
public int[] moveUp(int[] selectedIndices) {
    int[] newIndices = Arrays.copyOf(selectedIndices, selectedIndices.length);

    IntStream.range(0, selectedIndices.length)
            .filter(i -> selectedIndices[i] != i)
            .forEach(i -> {
                swap(actions, selectedIndices[i], selectedIndices[i] - 1);
                newIndices[i]--;
            });

    return newIndices;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are assuming that `selectedIndices` is sorted, you can easily determine which elements are to be moved up by comparing the index against its position in `selectedIndices`.  If the index is higher than its position, the associated element is to be moved.

```
public int[] moveUp(int[] selecteIndices) {
    // this assumes that selectedIndices is sorted
    int[] newSelection = IntStream.range(0, selectedIndices.length)
        .map(x -> selectedIndices[x] > x ? selectedIndices[x] - 1 : selectedIndices[x])
        .toArray();

    IntStream.range(0, selectedIndices.length)
        .filter(x -> selectedIndices[x] > x)
        .map(x -> selectedIndices[x])
        .forEachOrdered(i -> swap(actions, i - 1, i));

    return newSelection;
}
```

To minimize the amount of mental energy expended on thinking about "index of index", you can separately make the calculation of the first element to be moved.  To me, this is clearer, but that's subjective:

```
public int[] moveUp(int[] selecteIndices) {
    // this assumes that selecteIndices are sorted

    // index of the first element to move up or actions.size() if nothing needs to move
    int firstToMove = IntStream.range(0, selectedIndices.length)
        .filter(x -> selectedIndices[x] > x)
        .map(x -> selectedIndices[x])
        .findFirst()
        .orElse(actions.size());  

    int[] newSelection = Arrays.stream(selectedIndices)
        .map(i -> i >= firstToMove ? i - 1 : i)
        .toArray();

    Arrays.stream(selectedIndices)
        .filter(i -> i >= firstToMove)
        .forEachOrdered(i -> swap(actions, i - 1, i));

    return newSelection;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea :)